# ddclient with ipv6 in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, ipv6, dyndns, ddclient

i am trying to revive my old Thinkpad T60 as an Home Server, firstly for nextcloud.

I already use a dynamic dns service with portmapper for my raspberry pi, i simply used the `usev6 = if, if=eth0` configuration.

On my T60 i run Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (because i found that the newer versions would not support the old hardware) and when i install ddclient via `apt-get ddclient`, it installs ddclient version 3.8.2 which as far as i could find out does not have that 'usev6' fix yet.

is there a way to manually install the newer verison of ddclient or another way to update my ipv6 adress to the dyndns provider?

i got updating the ipv4 to work, but i need it to update the ipv6 adress. When i use the same configuration as in my raspi, the debug log returns "Ip adress ".

i'll include the full debug output as soon as i can.

Thanks if you read up to here!
volkerracho